# Remove margin App Android with Android Studio

Tags: android, margin

How can I remove the margin???

[image: margin photo]

This is the code of Layout

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">


        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lv"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

How can I remove the margin???

Comment: please show complete code of layout, there is another LinearLayout wraping you fragmentContainer ?

Comment: is this layout inside a fragment? It must be having a parent activity?

Comment: as far as i can guess, in your parent activity layout file there will be some Layout with margin.. remove those lines ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

and try removing

```
android:padding="10dp"
```

this also...

and like below

ACTIVITY

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

FRAGMENT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The above code should remove the padding you need to remove....

Comment: 1 more edit .. remove  `android:padding="10dp"` also, from LinearLayout1

Comment: YESSSS NOW WORKKK  :-) :-) THANKS

Comment: :D yes! you can mark my ans correct and upvote it.. glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:layout_margin="0dp"` to the elements you don't want a margin on.

Comment: Then change your `layout_width` in the `LinearLayout` to `match_parent` You might not be filling the whole element.

Comment: NO WORK<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_margin="0dp">




    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="0dp">



        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>